# Infragistics.UltraTree strange behaviour

Tags: xml, data-binding, infragistics

I use UltraTree method SetDataBinding to show xml tree structure. Xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StructDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Name="Document">
<List>  
    <StructElement Name="Number">
        <List/>
    </StructElement>    
    <StructElement Name="Author">
        <List>
            <StructElement Name="Name">
                <List>
                    <StructElement Name="FullName">
                        <List/>
                    </StructElement>
                    <StructElement Name="Adress">
                        <List/>
                    </StructElement>
                    <StructElement Name="Email">
                        <List/>
                    </StructElement>
                </List>
            </StructElement>
        </List>
    </StructElement>
</List>
</StructDocument>
```

Than I get the following: [image]

As you see a list of "Name" element child elements is missing. But when I change xml like this( simply change "Number" and "Author" elements order):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StructDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Name="Document">
<List>      
    <StructElement Name="Author">
        <List>
            <StructElement Name="Name">
                <List>
                    <StructElement Name="FullName">
                        <List/>
                    </StructElement>
                    <StructElement Name="Adress">
                        <List/>
                    </StructElement>
                    <StructElement Name="Email">
                        <List/>
                    </StructElement>
                </List>
            </StructElement>
        </List>
    </StructElement>
    <StructElement Name="Number">
        <List/>
    </StructElement>
</List>
</StructDocument>
```

, I get the following: [image]

I.e. now I see the desired behaviour, and all the xml elements are at the screen. I would like to ask how to achieve this without changing xml?

Comment: I would recommend posting this in the Infragistics forums to see if the behavior is expected and if so why: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/103.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try to reproduce your scenario in a small sample using your XML files and in a both cases (with both XML files) I get exception "**A column named 'List' already belongs to this DataTable: cannot set a nested table name to the same name.**" (maybe because my scenario is a little bit different)

Please take a look at attached sample and if you think that I didn't reproduce your scenario, please feel free to modify this sample and revert it back to me. I`ll be glad to reseacrh it for you.

Meanwhile will be better to post your questions in our web site http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/ . We will be glad to help you.

Here is the result from my test sample

[image]

Here is the my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StructDocument xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Name="Document" Description="">
  <StructElement Name="Number" Description ="Number of books 100">
  </StructElement>
  <StructElement Name="Author">
    <StructElement Name="Name" Description ="Stephen King">
      <StructElement Name="FullName" Description ="Stephen King full name">
      </StructElement>
      <StructElement Name="Adress" Description ="Stephen King address">
      </StructElement>
      <StructElement Name="Email" Description ="Stephen King email">
      </StructElement>
    </StructElement>
  </StructElement>
  <StructElement Name="Number" Description ="Number of books 20">
  </StructElement>
  <StructElement Name="Author">
    <StructElement Name="Name" Description ="George R. R. Martin">
      <StructElement Name="FullName" Description ="George R. R. Martin full name">
      </StructElement>
      <StructElement Name="Adress" Description ="George R. R. Martin address">
      </StructElement>
      <StructElement Name="Email" Description ="George R. R. Martin email">
      </StructElement>
    </StructElement>
  </StructElement>
</StructDocument>
```

and source code

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml("..\\..\\XMLFile1.xml");
            ultraTree1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            ultraTree1.ExpandAll();
            ultraTree1.ColumnSettings.AutoFitColumns = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTree.AutoFitColumns.ResizeAllColumns;
            ultraTree1.ColumnSettings.ColumnSets[0].Columns[0].Visible = false;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was with my binding. I created data structures of my own from xml ( like this: BindingList<StructElement> ). My case is closely matching this: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/45338/245614.aspx#245614.